# git ssh password?

Tags: ssh, git, remote

I'm trying to add a remote, but it's asking me for a ssh password?

I'm so confused, I've added the same remote on a different computer and it didn't ask me for a password. I've also added a different remote on this computer, but again no password.

I've set up my public key on the remote end, that seems to work, but again, it's asking for a password.

What's going on?

Answer (score 4):

Does ssh also ask you for a password?  (Probably.)

Is your private key installed correctly?  (Probably not.)  Make sure that your private key is installed on your local computer at `~/.ssh/id_dsa` (for DSA keys) and make sure that the permissions of `~/.ssh` are 700 -- if the permissions are 755, then SSH will refuse to read the key.  You can try increasing the verbosity of SSH to find out more information.

Answer (score 0):

is the user name the same on both machines? i.e. do they use the same key for authentication?

to make sure you use the same user, configure your remotes as `ssh://user@repo.or.cz/…`

Answer (score 0):

most likely this is an RSA key. When you generate one, don't specify a password. Sounds like you've updated the knownhosts file on the remote. connect with `ssh -vvvv server` to see what keys it's offering. If it's the wr